# What is wrong with this BASH regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

```
$ reg='(\.js)|(\.txt)|(\.html)$'
$ [[ 'flight_query.jsp' =~ $reg ]]
$ echo $?
0
```

*.jsp should not be matched based on the regular expression, but actually doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not? `\.js` is there in `.jsp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A useful comment was deleted. The comment suggested that operator precedence was the reason why the regular expression was passing. He suggested the following regular expression as a fix.

```
$ reg='(\.js|\.txt|\.html)$'
$ if [[ 'flight_query.jsp' =~ $reg ]]; then echo 'matches'; else echo "doesn't match"; fi
doesn't match
$ if [[ 'flight_query.js' =~ $reg ]]; then echo 'matches'; else echo "doesn't match"; fi
matches
```

This regular expression works as well `(\.js$)|(\.txt$)|(\.html$)`.